# Intermediate problem using Chain Rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $y=\frac{d}{dx} [\sin \sqrt{1+\cos (x)}]$ than, differentiate $x$.

$$\frac{d}{dx} [\sin \sqrt{1+\cos (x)}]$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx} [\sin (1+\cos (x))^{\frac{1}{2}}]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2} \cos (1+\cos (x))^{-\frac{1}{2}} (-\sin x)$$
$$=-\frac{\sin (x)}{2\cos (1+\cos (x))^\frac{1}{2}}$$

I found that the answer is wrong. I found the answer which was solved using

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{dx}{du} \frac{du}{dy} $$

But, I want to figure it out using [image]

---

I was trying to solve above question as I did for this

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\tan(x^2+1)]=\sec^2 (x^2+1) \cdot 2x$$

Comment: You seem to be differentiating $\sqrt{\sin(\cdots)}$, as opposed to $\sin\left(\sqrt{\cdots}\right)$

Comment: $x=\frac{d}{dx} [\sin \sqrt{1+\cos (x)}]$ is confusing since it is false. I guess you are trying to define
$y=\frac{d}{dx} [\sin \sqrt{1+\cos (x)}]$
and then trying to calculate $y$.

Comment: "differentiate $x$" is **not** the same as "differentiate with respect to $x$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin((1+\cos(x))^{1/2})$ is what you want to differentiate not what your expression is  , Let the inner expression be $g(x)$ and now use the chain rule .

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake from the first to the second line. Suddenly the square root went out of the sine. It should be
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \sin\left((1+\cos x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right).$$

Comment: Your answer is also correct. But, he has less reputation than, you that's why I had upvoted it. and, marked his as correct answer

Comment: @Istiak That's fine, no worries. :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin (\sqrt{1+ \cos x })$$

Note : differentiate the **outer function** first which is $~\sin x $ and then **inner function** which is $\sqrt{1+ \cos x} $

Step 1 differentiating the outer function :

$$~\cos(\sqrt{1+cos x }) ~\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{1+ \cos x }) $$

Step 2 Differentiating the inner function :

$$= \frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{1+ \cos x }) = \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos x)^{\frac {-1}{2}} { \frac{d}{dx}(1+ \cos x }) $$

step 3 :

$$ = { \frac{d}{dx}(1+ \cos x })= 0 -\sin x  $$
$$ = \frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{1+ \cos x }) = \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos x)^{\frac {-1}{2}} (-\sin x)   $$

$$ = \frac{-\sin x}{2 {\sqrt{1 +\cos x }}} $$

Final step  :

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\sin (\sqrt{1+ \cos x }) = ~- \frac {\cos ({\sqrt{1+ \cos x})}~\sin x}{2 {\sqrt{1 +\cos x }} }$$